# What is the general prognosis for a patient with an inoperable hip fracture?

Tags: hips, dementia

I have a friend whose elderly grandparent has recently suffered a hip fracture. The doctors involved have deemed the grandparent (who also has advanced dementia) too risky to operate on.

What is the general prognosis for the grandparent? I ask so that I can be the best friend I can in the meanwhile - I don't want to ask my friend if their grandparent is now on an inevitable path towards the end of their life, but if they are I want to have that in mind so I can be pre-emptively understanding, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can tell you what is going to happen to a patient exactly, because every Patient is different. However, the risk are:

[Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hip-fracture/basics/complications/con-20021033)

> A hip fracture can reduce your future independence and sometimes even
>   shorten your life. About half of people who have a hip fracture aren't
>   able to regain their ability to live independently.
>
> If a hip fracture keeps you immobile for a long time, the
>   complications can include:
>   Blood clots in your legs or lungs Bedsores Urinary tract infection
>   Pneumonia Further loss of muscle mass, increasing your risk of falls
>   and injury Additionally, people who've had a hip fracture are at
>   increased risk of weakened bones and further falls — which means a
>   significantly higher risk of having another hip fracture.

If you have a hip fracture you are at a higher risk for negative and life threatening complications and decreased independence and quality of life as you can do less (mobility, etc). Therapy and rehab can help you, however the hip is still fractured and if the patient has dementia they generally do not follow all of what the doctor prescribes.

[Ncbi.nlm.nih.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3102807/)